# How to connect 2 thermistors for battery protection?

Tags: battery-charging, circuit-design, design, lithium-ion, thermistor

I'm planning to use [BQ24100](http://www.ti.com/product/BQ24100) for charging Li-ion cells connected in parallel.

Unfortunately, the cells have to be separated by few centimeters, so I have to use 2 thermistors. So, how to connect 2 thermistors to BQ24100, since the IC has only one pin for thermistor?

Comment: There isn't any way to do that, really. I think you will have to implement a window comparator to detect out-of-range temperature for one of the cells. When temp is out of range, you can pull the TS pin high or low to suspend charging.

Comment: Or you could just sense one cell and make the assumption that both cells are at the same temperature. Whether that is acceptable depends on many things.

Comment: Don't plan to use parallel cells. Without precise matching of charge and discharge curves the parallel cells won't last long. Find a bigger single cell.

Comment: Isn't it enough to just buy the same cells from the same manufacturer and seller?

Comment: I believe that opinions vary on this. It will also depend on how fast you plan to charge and discharge the cells.